# Vuetify v-text-field change value

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

how can i manipulate input value.
Show hier is example

```
`https://jsfiddle.net/mbqjp4ax/`
```

if number greater than 5, number 9 should be entered.
if I enter more than 5 it works fine but if I keep typing it will not work as expected.

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-model-on-Components

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You dont need to use getElementsByTagName and such things in vue. And $refs have a limited usage too.  You should just use v-model.

Here your fiddle fixed

https://jsfiddle.net/pm9zwesr/

```
<v-text-field
    label="Price"
    v-model="price"
    @input="up">
</v-text-field>

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data () {
    return {
      price: 123.45
    }
  },
  methods: {
    up (){
      if (parseFloat(this.price) > 5) {
        this.$nextTick(() => {
          this.price = 9
        })        
      }
    },

    reset () {
      this.price = 0
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: it is not good practice to use `input` event and `v-model` directive together.

Comment: It's great thank you very much. Happy that this works. But @max-sinev do you have other solution than v-model?

Comment: @Vin it's pretty similar just with `@input` and `:value` binding because 
`v-model` is syntax sugar for `:value`+`@input` https://jsfiddle.net/maxsinev/pm9zwesr/18/